# How to use a key in an esriRequest call

Tags: javascript, api, curl, request, arcrest

I have been making calls to a previously free API using `esriRequest`

```
var layersRequest = esriRequest({
    url: base_url,
    content: { "latitude": lat,
                "longitude": long,
                "riskCategory": risk,
                "siteClass": siteClass,
                "title":"Default"},
    dataType:'jsonp',
    handleAs: "json",
    callbackParamName: "callback"
}); ...
```

Now the API requires a key; which I have:

```
const key = 'xI234fg543example23';
```

**The above is just an **example key**; not real

The API documentation says to "Include your key in the api-key field of your request headers to authenticate like this:

```
curl --header "api-key: [your_api_key]" -X GET "https://api-hazards.atcouncil.org/public/v1/[load_category].json?lat=[lat]&lng=[lng]"
```

How do I correctly apply this using `esriRequest`?

Comment: remove your key from this question (probably should deactivate it if possible since edit history is available). Don't share your key with anyone.

Comment: It's not a real key. I just made it up as an example.

Comment: OK, great!  Looks like javascript code?

Comment: Yep, all javascript. Just not sure how to apply the key in the javascript using the example from the API documentation (curl).

Comment: I think you can just build it from strings and insert the variable -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922647/how-do-i-combine-2-javascript-variables-into-a-string

Answer (score 1):

In terms of syntax, the request would be

```
curl --header "api-key: xI234fg543example23" -X GET "https://api-hazards.atcouncil.org/public/v1/[load_category].json?lat=[lat]&lng=[lng]"
```

If you want to pass the API key in, you can concatenate the key variable with your string, something like:

```
var curlrequest = 'curl --header "api-key: ' + key + '" -X GET "https://api-hazards.atcouncil.org/public/v1/[load_category].json?lat=[lat]&lng=[lng]"'
```

More examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124032/js-strings-vs-concat-method

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922647/how-do-i-combine-2-javascript-variables-into-a-string

Comment: OK, but this just gives me a string variable and does not really make a request. I still have to utilize it within `esriRequest`. I do think adding this as the `url:` would work.

Comment: How are you passing in the lat long? Treat key the same way.

Comment: Please edit the question with what you have (successfully?) tried with the latlong. Note I think the last comment has a duplicate lat=

Comment: The lat and long are passed in as parameters. I've already tried adding ...?api-key=xI234fg543example23&lat=[lat]&lng=[lng] and it doesn't work. It has to be added as a header somehow within the esriRequest methodology.*Note: [lat] and [lat] are just holders.

Comment: Since [key] is also just a placeholder... Sorry, I primarily work in Python and my javascript class is far in the past. But you should be able to follow the same method you used to insert the lat long parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HttpClient library?

Try this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", "xI234fg543example23");
client.get('http://some/thing?with=arguments', function(response) {
    // do something with response
});
```

Comment: No, because I have spatial data (long, lat) as parameters and am utilizing the `esri/request` and `esri/config` packages from the `ArcGIS API for Javascript 3x` I don't want to bring in `ajax` or `HTTPClient`. So thats really not a viable solution except as a last resort.